# What does the term "seed lexicon" means?

Tags: nlp, language-model, research

I am reading a research paper (NLP) and found the phrase "seed lexicon".

Could someone please explain it in detail?

Edit :

A sample paper
[Leveraging Affective Bidirectional Transformers for Offensive Language
Detection](https://aclanthology.org/2020.osact-1.17.pdf)

Check 3rd page right column 5th line.

Comment: You must at least provide a source or definition/context of the term

Comment: Thank you, I added the source

Comment: Table 2 in that paper is a partial seed lexicon. The authors mean a lexicon (dictionary) of seeds (for training the model).